# recaptcha calling callback from outside?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

How to trigger the google recaptcha callback function manually?

the recaptcha is set like this:

```
grecaptcha.render(“recaptcha”, {
    sitekey: // some site key,
    callback: // some callback function
});
```

is it possible to trigger that “callback” function in the grecaptcha variable somehow to pass some values?

something similar to this (this does not work):

`grecaptcha.callback("foo");`

thank you!

Comment: Are you asking if you can pass the values to google and have google use the parameters in the callback? Or are you asking if you can re-use the callback function yourself and pass values to it?